# Show Real Time, Date, Day of the Week in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

How to show real time, date, day in this format?

[image]

The time should be actual (which runs the seconds count).

Thanks guys!

Comment: take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/fdq5173y/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To update time panel every second we should use `setInterval()` function.

To format date the way you need the best approach is to use `moment.js` library. The code is shortened greatly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var momentNow = moment();
        $('#date-part').html(momentNow.format('YYYY MMMM DD') + ' '
                            + momentNow.format('dddd')
                             .substring(0,3).toUpperCase());
        $('#time-part').html(momentNow.format('A hh:mm:ss'));
    }, 100);
});
```

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/zf80q3nh/)

Comment: I got moment is not defined error . can you please explain why?

Comment: I fixed it. Some javascript collision cause error

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SetInterval` in javascript and run it after every 1 second.
Look for the given example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demonew"></p>
<script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
  dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
  mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.getElementById("demonew").innerHTML = today;
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use :
  <script>
    var mydate=new Date()
    var year=mydate.getYear()

if (year < 1000)
    year+=1900

var day=mydate.getDay() // Current Day of week - 2
var month=mydate.getMonth() // Current Month 2
var daym=mydate.getDate() // Current Date -24
var h=mydate.getHours(); //Hours
var m=mydate.getMinutes();//Minutes
var s=mydate.getSeconds();//Seconds
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}
```

Take 2 arrays

```
var dayarray=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",
                        "Friday","Saturday")
var montharray=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
                        "July","August","September","October","November","December")

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =h+":"+m+":"+s+" "+dayarray[day]+", "+montharray[month]+" "+daym+", "+year;

 var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
  //This will update time 


 </script>
  <body onload="startTime()">

  <div id="txt"></div>

  </body>
```